# Xcode requires Java runtime, but is "not connected to the internet"?

Tags: java, xcode, macos, qt

When I try to open an Xcode project, it tells me "To open “Xcode,” you need to install a Java runtime, but you are not connected to the Internet.". Now, if I right-click and click "Open with Xcode 4.3.2", it works fine, and that's what I've been doing.

However, I've now downloaded Qt Creator and when I try to compile it tells me "Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild.". I try to run this and I get the same Java error.

Unlike the error says, I happen to be connected to the internet, so I went and downloaded the latest version of Java and installed it. But that made no difference whatsoever and now I'm still getting the same errors.

Why does Xcode need Java? Why does Qt Creator need Xcode? How can I fix this? I feel like I'm pushing water uphill with a fork, and I'm losing my mind.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator needs Xcode, because Qt Creator is just an IDE, it comes with no compilers. Xcode is an entire package of tools, including compilers, the IDE, documentation, device simulators, and multiple additional tools.

Xcode does need Java, it will download it automatically. Even then, you would need the connection anyway since Xcode by default doesn't come with command line tools that Qt Creator needs. Those tools *also* need to be downloaded. You start the download from the terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

You can also download those tools from the apple developer download site.